# Accessing Firebase in Node.JS/express globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

In my main express file, `app.js`, I set up Firebase:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "../Wrapper-adfd67bc8c36.json",
  databaseURL: "https://wrapper.firebaseio.com"
});
```

But when I try to access it in a routing file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    functionThatUsesFirebase(req.params.id);

    res.send(req.params.id);
});
```

I get the error:

```
firebase is not defined.
```

So then I tried just adding Firebase to the routing file itself:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "../Wrapper-adfd67bc8c36.json",
  databaseURL: "https://wrapper.firebaseio.com"
});

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    functionThatUsesFirebase(req.params.id);

    res.send(req.params.id);
});
```

I get the console error:

```
Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists.
```

How can I make Firebase accessible to all of my routing files? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Node, [all modules are "Singletons"](http://fredkschott.com/post/2013/12/node-js-cookbook---designing-singletons/), also referred to as [Module Caching](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_caching) in the Node.js docs. If you call `initializeApp()` once in your `app.js` and then require the `firebase` again in your router, your router's `firebase` will actually have the same global settings as the `firebase` in your `app.js`. This is the reason why you're getting your error `Firebase App name '[DEFAULT]' already exists`.

Once you call `initializeApp()` in your `app.js`, no subsequent calls will need to be made to `initializeApp()` anywhere else in your code. Whenever/wherever you need to interact with firebase just `require('firebase')` and use it.

Comment: Thank you! Also, beginner question, but I'm used to linking all of my .js files into a .html file, where they all can reference each other. Is there a way to reference a .js file from a router file?

Comment: Just do `require('./path/to/js/file');` wherever you need to access that `.js` file. [Module docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_modules)

Comment: When I `console.log(classes);` just to test if classes are getting imported with `var classes = require('../routes/Classes');` or `var classes = require('../routes/Classes');`, I get `{}`. `Classes.js` is just a file full of different classes.

Comment: And when I try `classes.Queue()` (a function in classes), i get the error that `classes.Queue()` is not a function.

Comment: @KieranGill Are you actually exporting the functions that you want to call in `Classes.js` using `module.exports`?

Comment: I surround the functions I want to call in `Classes.js` with `module.exports = { // code }` correct? I receive the error `TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object`

Comment: @KieranGill I think your going beyond the scope of this particular question at this point, you should probably create additional questions for any other problems you're having.